# Creating an .ipa file with a Cordova Script

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Can successfully create a ipa file based on my Cordova project manually within XCode but I want to be able to build the ipa file with the Cordova script, so that it can automatically run on the script on my build server.

I ran:

```
cross-env CORDOVA_PLATFORM=ios vue-cli-service cordova-build-ios --device --automaticProvisioning true"
```

Unfortunately, no ipa file gets generated. The script creates the www directory but doesn't go further to create the ipa file:

```
DONE  Build complete. The www directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

 INFO  executing "cordova clean" in folder /Users/christiankl/IdeaProjects/Cordova
 INFO  executing "cordova build ios --release" in folder /Users/christiankl/IdeaProjects/Cordova

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about the vue-cli-service you are using, it seems that when you call the **'cordova-build-ios --device --automaticProvisioning true'**, it is loosing the flags, namely, the **--device** flag. If --device flag is not passed into the **cordova build** execution, you wont get an *.ipa file.

The log you posted seems to indicate what i said:

> INFO  executing "cordova build ios --release" in folder /Users/christiankl/IdeaProjects/Cordova

So, try to change your script, validating if or how you can pass the flags correctly